# Start application when file is received via Bluetooth

Tags: android, android-intent, bluetooth, intentfilter

My application should start when any file is received via Bluetooth.

Please tell me, which intent is fired when a file is received via Bluetooth?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no such specific intent action which tells that a file is downloaded. However, you should listen for the following broadcast to detect that a phone is disconnected and then check programatically if a file is downloaded.

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.bluetooth.device.action.ACL_DISCONNECTED"/>
</intent-filter>
```